# Firestore save data in strange formation using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to save data on Firebase but the data is stored in strange way although the value is string like this:

```
Description
"TextEditingController#d9024(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: 
TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))"
Price
"TextEditingController#c11e0(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: 
TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))"
Title
"TextEditingController#dcebb(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: 
TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))"
UID
"gWYqXqsvTdVI1Sfa8MP4SrFTEmB2"
```

here is my code:

```
final adTitleController = TextEditingController();
final priceController = TextEditingController();
final adDescription = TextEditingController();

Future<void> createAds() async {
CollectionReference ads = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Ads');

String? adid = ads.id.toString();

String? title = adTitleController.toString();
String? desc = adDescription.toString();
String? price = priceController.toString();
String? userId;
String? adId;
ads.add({
  "UID": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid,
  "AdId": adId,
  "Title": title,
  "Description": desc,
  "Price": price,
});
}
```

Comment: No its just null

Comment: `String? title = adTitleController.toString();` => `String? title = adTitleController.text`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a text from the controller you need to use `text` property of `TextEditingController`

```
String? title = adTitleController.text.toString();
String? desc = adDescription.text.toString();
String? price = priceController.text.toString();
```